# UDP async - Why make a new UdpClient

Tags: c#, asynchronous, udp

```
class UdpExample
{
    private UdpClient Client = new UdpClient(25971);

    public UdpExample()
    {
        Client.BeginReceive(DataReceived, Client);
    }

    private void DataReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        UdpClient c = (UdpClient)ar.AsyncState
        IpEndPoint receivedIpEndPoint = new IpEndPoint(IpAddress.Any, 0);
        Byte[] data = c.EndReceive(ar, ref receivedIpEndPoint);
    }
}
```

In the above code, why is a new `UdpClient` (c) made from `ar.AsyncState`?
Why can it not just use `Client.EndReceive` (using the classwide `UdpClient`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ar.AsyncState` is `object`, it's not a *new* `UdpClient`, it's the one **you** *passed in*.

Why? Because if you have lots of these things floating around, you know which one you are working on, However it can be used for more than just a `UdpClient` you can pass in anything, and know with certainty it belongs to the `Begin` you started with.

Let's look at the parameter in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginreceive?view=netframework-4.8)

> `state` Object - A user-defined object that contains information about
>   the receive operation. This object is passed to the requestCallback
>   delegate when the operation is complete.